# Copy input to clipboard over SSH?

Tags: ssh, xorg, clipboard

Here's my usage case:

- I'm often connected to other computers over SSH for work and I often need to copy and paste documents/text from the server to locally running editors for writing examples and sharing text.
- Often, if the text is small enough, I'll simply copy the output from my terminal program (gnome-terminal at the moment) and paste it.
- However, when it comes to entire documents, my options are quite limited. I can either copy the document chunk-by-chunk, or `scp` it to the local machine.

Is there a way to use a program such as `xclip` which will allow me to copy remote `stdin` to the local X server's clipboard? Something to the effect of:

```
cat myconffile.conf | sed {...} | copy-over-ssh-to-local-clipboard
```

would be awesome. Does something exist to make this possible?

Comment: Some more solutions are available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1152362) on the StackOverflow SE sister site.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you run ssh with X forwarding, this is transparent: remote commands (including `xclip`) have access to your X server (including its keyboard). Make sure you have `ForwardX11 yes` in your `~/.ssh/config` and `X11Forwarding yes` in the server `sshd_config` (depending on your distributions, these options may be on or off by default).

```
<myconffile.conf sed {...} | xclip -i
```

There are other ways of working on remote files that may be more convenient, for example mounting remote directories on your local machine with [SSHfs](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html), or opening remote files in Emacs with [Tramp](http://www.gnu.org/software/tramp/). If you have ssh and [FUSE](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/) set up and SSHfs installed, SSHfs is as easy as `mkdir ~/net/myserver; sshfs myserver:/ ~/net/myserver`. If you have ssh set up and Emacs installed, Tramp is as easy as opening `/myserver:/path/to/file`.

Comment: Any security vulnerabilities to running things this way by default in the conf file?

Comment: No. All the x11 traffic is forwarded through the SSH channel.

Comment: @TKKocheran Not really. On the server side, none. On the client side, a little, in that it gives the server administrator a way into your client, but in 99% of cases the server admin has a way anyway; see [If someone is signed into SSH on my computer, can I access their computer?](http://superuser.com/questions/202123/if-someone-is-signed-into-ssh-on-my-computer-can-i-access-their-computer/202970#202970)

Comment: doesn't work (I also restarted ssh, installed xclip, started a new ssh session). Test:
```
ssh user@remote
micro a.txt
write "text"
mark, ctrl+x (text is cut)
ctrl+v: pastes old text copied on local host from browser
```

Comment: @Marius Your comment conspicuously omits checking that X forwarding is enabled. Does `ssh user@remote xterm` open an xterm window with a shell on the remote host? If not, solve that.

Comment: I see. I don't have xterm, nor X, installed on the remote server, it's a server. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

You don't need anything special; since `xclip` works over `stdin`, just

```
ssh remotehost xclip < myconf.conf
```

Why would it need to be modified with `sed`?  `ssh` is transparent to data when not used as a terminal, and is commonly used in pipelines such as

```
tar cfz - somedir | ssh remotehost 'cd destdir; tar xfz -'`
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it from within an existing SSH session? I'd really prefer not to have to open up another terminal window if I already have one open to the machine in question.

Comment: And sed` is just there as an example, if I'd like to perform any processing on the `stdin` before copying it to the clipboard, I'd like that option.

Comment: No, there's no way to inject data into an existing `ssh` session (it wouldn't be very secure if you could). You can set up the `ssh` `ControlMaster` stuff to multiplex additional connections over an existing one, but it's not really something for beginners and you *still* do it the same way afterward, by switching to another local terminal and running the command above (which does *not* open a new terminal window).

Comment: @NaftuliKay For a solution that works inside your normal SSH session, see [my answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/498270).

Answer (score 7):

Here's how you would do it on OSX from your local machine

```
ssh remotehost.com "<some/file.txt" | pbcopy
```

Answer (score 3):

if your local machine is running windows(7+) you can just use this from the CommandLine:

```
ssh user@server cat /home/user/file | clip
```

Answer (score 3):

Very similar to @d-raev's and @william-casarin solutions, however, it is different so I'm sharing what worked for me.

**The command**

```
ssh user@host "cat <myconffile.conf" | xclip -sel clip
```

**Explanation**

This is using `ssh` to create a secure tunnel,  login to `user` @ `host` or `ip`, then execute `cat` to print the contents of `<myconffile.conf` to `stdout` then piping that to the command `xclip -sel clip` on your local machine, which places the contents of `<myconffile.conf` into the clipboard on your local machine.

**Real-world example usage**

I use this command structure for tasks such as  pasting ssh keys into github (allowing a simple ctrl-V or paste selection after I run the command) on with Bash on Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04. Check out `man ssh`, `man cat`, and `man xclip` for behavior and option details.

Comment: This even works to copy _from_ headless servers, where `xclip` won't run as there is no X.

Answer (score 2):

~/.ssh/config:

```
Host REMOTEHOST
    ...
    ForwardX11 yes
```

/etc/ssh/sshd_config:

```
X11Forwarding yes
```

bash:

```
$ xclip -o | ssh REMOTEHOST 'DISPLAY=:0 xclip -i'
```

Comment: doesn't work (I also restarted ssh, installed xclip, started a new ssh session). Test:
```
ssh user@remote
micro a.txt
write "text"
mark, ctrl+x (text is cut)
ctrl+v: pastes old text copied on local host from browser
```

Answer (score 0):

I have similar issue with LUbuntu's `lxterminal` (tested various terminals) pasting clipboard to an `ssh` session. If clipboard has more than about 100 bytes the session timeouts and fails.

If I connect via ssh to almost any CentOS 5.x server and then connect to the target server, clipboard paste works without any issue for any reasonable data size.

Answer (score 0):

**Copying from a headless server to local clipboard, from inside your usual SSH session:**

1. Install `ncat` on your local and remote machine. (On your remote machine you can also do with `nc` or plain `telnet`, but on the local machine we need the options to execute commands (`-c` / `-e`) which are not available in `nc` in usual distributions like Debian and Ubuntu.)

   ```
   apt install nmap
   ```
2. On your local machine, set up a server listening on the local interface that will copy content coming in on port 10009 to your X clipboard:

   ```
   ncat --keep-open --listen --sh-exec "xclip -selection clipboard" localhost 10009
   ```

   Or use the equivalent shorthand version:

   ```
   ncat -klc "xclip -sel c" localhost 10009
   ```
3. SSH into the remote machine in such a way that a reverse tunnel is established from port 10008 of the remote machine to port 10009 on your local machine (where your server is listening). You can use that SSH session for your normal work.

   ```
   ssh -R 10008:localhost:10009 user@example.com
   ```
4. When you want to copy a file's content from remote machine to local clipboard, execute in the SSH shell:

   ```
   ncat --send-only localhost 10008 < file.txt
   ```

   And of course, that's nicer when packaged as a shell shortcut or script. We could call it `rclip` for "[copy to] remote clipboard" in analogy to the well-known [`xclip`](https://github.com/astrand/xclip).

**Advantages**

- No need to open another SSH session to the remote machine.
- No need for `xclip` on the remote machine, so it works if you can't install it or can't use it because it's a headless server without X.

**Security**

We do `ncat -l localhost 10009` for the server, which means it listens only on the network interface with the `localhost` IP address. This local loop interface only allows connections from your own machine (including, in this case, those reverse tunneled in via SSH). So even if you are not behind a firewall, your port 10009 is not exposed to anyone on the Internet.

**Source**

Adapted from the gist [dergachev/ssh-forward-clipboard.md](https://gist.github.com/dergachev/8259104) to work for Linux. That gist also contains instructions for how to make the SSH reverse tunnel a default.

Answer (score 0):

[Far Manager Linux port](https://github.com/elfmz/far2l) supports synchronizing clipboard between local and remote host. You just open local far2l, do "ssh somehost" inside, run remote far2l in that ssh session and get remote far2l working with your local clipboard.

It supportes Linux, *BSD and OS X; I made a [special putty build](https://github.com/unxed/putty4far2l) to utilize this functionality from windows also.

Answer (score -1):

https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Base64

You can convert your clipboard data with Base64 to ASCII text. Then you can push that through inside an already existing SSH connection.

Comment: Why convert to anything? It's already text in this case and even if it was binary there would be no reason you couldn't send it across a pipeline like this.

Comment: clipboard could contain binary data, e.g.: a compiled application

Comment: Yes it could, but why would that be a problem? Binary data can be transferred through a pipe and ssh tunnel.